# $ git push -u origin main remote: Repository not found. fatal: repository 'https://github.com/fretagi/pirple-apple.git/' not found

Tags: git, push-notification, gitlab, github

Estou tentando fazer o push de acordo com:

> git remote add origin https://github.com/fretagi/pirple-projects-apple.git
> git branch -M main
> git push -u origin main

mas ele da esse erro:

```
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

entao fiz uma pesquisa e me pediram para correr alguns comandos, mas sem sucesso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguma dica de como ultrapassar este problema?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você tenha clonado um repositorio e agora quer adicionar ao seu github, seja como for utilize o comando `git remote remove origin` em seguida adicione o repositorio desejado `git remote add origin https://github.com/fretagi/pirple-projects-apple.git`

Comment: Ola,ja consegui resolver depois de muita pesquisa, tive usar o `set url` e depois todo o path, e ai ele funcionou. Muito obrigado pela dica.